# HEROKU - LetsEncrypt not secure in windows, fine on Mac?

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I installed SSL letsEncrypt via Heroku dashboard. Everything works perfectly fine on Mac.

However, if you use Windows, the status bar shows that it is NOT secure which ultimately breaks the site when you try to submit forms and access jquery features...

Anyone experience this before?  Is there a solution or should I just buy an SSL ticket to resolve this?

The site is https://www.givingdocs.com

[image: Mac]

[image: PC]

Comment: It looks like you're simply on `http://www.givingdocs.com` in the Windows browser. Add http**s**?

Comment: Additionally, you might want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. How to do that on Heroku will depend on your tech stack.